# Representing a sine wave given LSB/V

Tags: c, signals, frequency, wave, trigonometry

I create a sine wave of a voltage signal. 
How can I represent that in the scale factor 128 LSB/Volts ?
The amplitude is 180 Volts.
Obs: I guess LSB is "LOW SIGNIFICANT BIT".

My code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;
    short value;
    double amp = 180, freq = 60, freq_samp;

    freq_samp = atof(argv[2]);
    printf("\n** Sample frequency: %f **",freq_samp);
    while(1) {
        value = amp*sin(2*i*PI*freq/freq_samp);
        printf("\nValue = %d",value);
        i = i + 1;
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just creat a LSB variable e then do amplitude*LSB:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;
    short value, LSB;
    double amp = 180, freq = 60, freq_samp;

    freq_samp = atof(argv[2]);
    printf("\n** Sample frequency: %f **",freq_samp);
    while(1) {
        value = LSB*amp*sin(2*i*PI*freq/freq_samp);
        printf("\nValue = %d",value);
        i = i + 1;
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```